# How to programmatically setup Azure B2C federated accounts

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I have a B2C tenant that is using an Azure AD tenant as an OIDC provider using IEF and a custom policy as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom).  When I login to B2C with a user from the federated tenant, it creates a special user in the B2C tenant (username shows name of custom identity provider).  Is there a way to programmatically add these federated users to the B2C tenant?  That is the desired functionality for my scenario but have been unable to accomplish it using AAD Graph API.

Comment: were you ever able to accomplish this?